# Can someone help me learn how to use the javascript connections code?

Tags: xpages, ibm-connections

I am trying to access data from Connections.  I need to use some of the javascript api code:  https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/SBTPlayground.nsf/JavaScriptSnippets.xsp#snippet=Social_Files_Get_My_Files

But I do not know how to build the app using xPages.  I tried a new xPage and pasted the code into a script block but I get compile errors.

Can someone show me how to use the Javascript samples from the playground?

Comment: look at the TroubleTickets Example on OpenNTF.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the quick reply.  I have code like that working just fine.  However, I need to use code like the sample in my link above.  It's more of a JavaScript app.  I don't see that being used in the ticket tracking app unless I missed something.

Comment: the TroubleTicket app uses the OSGI to connect to the backend services.  the examples above require a layer like the OSGI plugins.  There is no pure JavaScript layer

Comment: I am trying to build a simple home page in xPages that shows some basic information from Connections. I want to show my files in a dataView.  I tried using the following:
<xp:this.data>
<xe:fileServiceData var="fileServiceData1" endpoint="connectionsSSO">
    <xe:this.serviceType>
      <xe:connectionsFileData></xe:connectionsFileData>
    </xe:this.serviceType>
    <xe:this.urlParameters>
      <xe:urlParameter value="100" name="ps"></xe:urlParameter>
    </xe:this.urlParameters>
</xe:fileServiceData>
</xp:this.data>

Continued....

Comment: The code above does not work  I only get 10 files.  So I found the javascript code on the playground that does work.  When I add {ps:100} in the url of the jscript code from the link above, it got my 100 file list.  However, I can't figure out how to use the javascript code from the link above in an xPages application.

Comment: NVM I was able to use the code from the tracking database with a couple minor tweaks.  It's exactly what I needed.  THANK YOU SO MUCH Paul!!!

Answer (score 2):

Paul's suggestion to use the openntf ticket tracking was brilliant!  Here is the code that ultimately worked.  Thank you again Paul!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xe:dataView id="myFilesDataView" var="file" rows="110"
        columnTitles="true" styleClass="filesDataView">
        <xe:this.extraColumns>
            <xe:viewExtraColumn columnTitle="Filetype">
            </xe:viewExtraColumn>
            <xe:viewExtraColumn columnTitle="Size">
            </xe:viewExtraColumn>
        </xe:this.extraColumns>
        <xe:this.summaryColumn>
            <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnTitle="Filename">
            </xe:viewSummaryColumn>
        </xe:this.summaryColumn>
        <xp:this.value>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                try{
                    var filesService = new com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.files.FileService( "connectionsSSO" ); 
                    //  ps:100 is page size of 100 files
                    var myFiles = filesService.getMyFiles({ps:100});
                    viewScope.myFilesAvailable = true;
                    return myFiles;
                }catch(exception){
                    println("getFiles value error: " + exception);
                    viewScope.myFilesAvailable = false;
                    return null;
                }}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:panel xp:key="noRows" id="emptyMyFilesPanel">
                <xp:div styleClass="lotusWidgetBody">
                    <xp:text>
                        <xp:this.value>
                            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                return (viewScope.myFilesAvailable ? "No  files found." : "Files unavailable.");
                            }]]>
                        </xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:div>
            </xp:panel>
            <xp:panel id="summaryPanel" xp:key="summary" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <xp:link escape="true" id="link7" target="_blank"
                    text="#{javascript:return file.getTitle();}" styleClass="dataViewLink">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return file.getContentUrl();}]]>
                    </xp:this.value>
                </xp:link>
            </xp:panel>
            <xp:panel id="typePanel" xp:key="extra0"
                style="width: 20%;white-space:nowrap;">
                <xp:text>
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return file.getType();}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
            </xp:panel>
            <xp:panel id="sizePanel" xp:key="extra1"
                style="width: 15%;white-space:nowrap;">
                <xp:text>
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        var size = file.getSize();
                        var kilobyte = 1024;
                        var megabyte = kilobyte *1024;
                        if(size < kilobyte) {
                            return (size + " B");
                        }else if(size < megabyte) {
                            return (Math.round(size/kilobyte) + " KB");
                        }else {
                            return (Math.round(size/megabyte) + " MB");
                        }}]]>
                    </xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:dataView>
</xp:view>
```